# proper way of passing more than one data in array params: php

Tags: php, arrays

This is my foreach

```
foreach( $artist_price as $paypal_email => $price ) {
    // Calculation.
    $paypal_id_array[] = $paypal_email;

    $commission = ($commission_percent/100) * $price;
    $remaining_price = $price - $commission;
    $remaining_price_array[] = $remaining_price;
}
```

This is how i am passing my values:

```
// Params.
$bodyParams = array(
    "receiverList.receiver(1).amount" => $remaining_price_array[0],
    "receiverList.receiver(2).email" => $paypal_id_array[1],
    "receiverList.receiver(2).amount" => $remaining_price_array[1],
    "receiverList.receiver(3).email" => $paypal_id_array[2],
    "receiverList.receiver(3).amount" => $remaining_price_array[2],
    "receiverList.receiver(4).email" => $paypal_id_array[3],
    "receiverList.receiver(4).amount" => $remaining_price_array[3],
    "receiverList.receiver(5).email" => $paypal_id_array[4],
    "receiverList.receiver(5).amount" => $remaining_price_array[4],
    "receiverList.receiver(6).email" => $paypal_id_array[5],
    "receiverList.receiver(6).amount" => $remaining_price_array[5],
    "receiverList.receiver(7).email" => $paypal_id_array[6],
    "receiverList.receiver(7).amount" => $remaining_price_array[6],
    "receiverList.receiver(8).email" => $paypal_id_array[7],
    "receiverList.receiver(8).amount" => $remaining_price_array[7]
);
```

Is there any proper way to add "receiverList.receiver(8).email" and "receiverList.receiver(8).amount" how much it contains in the foreach loop. e.g: if there are only two merchants than just it goes upto 2 merchants. the way i am doing is static and it also gives error of undefined values. although the code is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything in the `foreach` loop:

```
$bodyParams = array();
$count = 1;
foreach( $artist_price as $paypal_email => $price ) {
    // Calculation.
    $commission = ($commission_percent/100) * $price;
    $remaining_price = $price - $commission;

    $bodyParams["receiverList.receiver($count).email"] = $paypal_email;
    $bodyParams["receiverList.receiver($count).amount"] = $remaining_price;
    $count++;
}
```